# how to set java option per webapplication in weblogic

Tags: java, logging, weblogic

how can i set a java_option - in my case java.util.logging.manager - per web application in weblogic ?

I cant set in globally, since weblogic logging also uses this same log manager. 
I only need the logs from the web applications - to point to a different log manager.

thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you can do this with log4j, not sure about a cmd line java option directly

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in log4j for each application and have it written to different log file. You can specify the file path in log4j.appender.file.File variable